# how to uncompress .tar and lz4 file in qt?

Tags: qt, zip, tar, lz4

i make a application in `Qt` for extract **zip** , **tar** and **lz4** files, So i use `QuaZip` and `zlib` library!

**The step one (Qt cmd):**

```
cd C:\Qt\zlib-1.2.8

mingw32-make -f win32/Makefile.gcc
```

**and step two:**

```
cd C:\Qt\quazip-0.7

qmake "CONFIG+=release" "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Qt/zlib-1.2.8" "LIBS+=-LC:/Qt/zlib- 
1.2.8 -lz"

mingw32-make
```

**step three add below code to .pro in QT project:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/zlib-1.2.8
LIBS += -LC:/Qt/zlib-1.2.8 -lz
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/quazip-0.7/quazip
LIBS += -LC:/Qt/quazip-0.7/quazip/release -lquazip
```

**and the last step can unzip and zip file's like this code:**

```
#include <JlCompress.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   JlCompress::compressFile("C:/test.zip", "C:/test.txt");
   JlCompress::extractDir("C:/test.zip", "C:/");
   return 0;
}
```

Now my problem is i can't extract .tar and lz4 file's. please help me!

Comment: zlib does data compression, .tar is a file format. They are not the same and zlib has no means of creating or opening .tar's. You will need to link an archive library like *libtar* in addition to zlib to do it.

Comment: How i can do? Please show tutorial to me mr